# Can someone make this script simpler?

Tags: javascript, css, hide, show

I am currently using 2 javascript functions, and it should only be necessary with one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

div.menubox1 {
background-color: #323232;
height: 50px;

}

div.menubox2 {
background-color: #323232;
height: 50px;

}

div.relative {
position: relative;
top: 26%;
left: 7.6%;
border: 0px;
width: 200px;
}

</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.menubox1").click(function(){
        $("p1").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.menubox2").click(function(){
        $("p2").toggle();
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="menubox1"><div class="relative"> » test 1</div></div>
<p1>This is a paragraph with little content.</p1>

<div class="menubox2"><div class="relative"> » test 2</div></div>
<p2>This is another small paragraph.</p2>

</body>
</html>
```

This does works e.g. each DIV will show/hide the paragraphs, but surely I the script can be adapted to take the information directly from the effected DIV and do the show/hide action.

**EDIT:**

I think I have explained this wrong. I am referring to this part:

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.menubox1").click(function(){
            $("p1").toggle();
        });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("div.menubox2").click(function(){
            $("p2").toggle();
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Surely needs to be changed into 1 function and not 2 or however many DIVs I will need to show/hide.

Comment: remove `</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps CodeReview...but check their *guidelines* first.

Comment: `$("div.menubox1,div.menubox2").click(function(){
       $(this).next().toggle();
})`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ONE class and add the event handler to the class instead - to differentiate between the divs, use ID. Also change `<p1` / `<p2` to `<p id="p1"` and `<p id="p2"`

```js
$(function() {
  $("div.menubox").on("click",function() {
    var idx = this.id.replace(/menubox/, ""); // or use data-idx attribute
    $("#p" + idx).toggle(); // or $(this).next().toggle(); if p is always after the div
  });
});
```

```css
div.menubox {
  background-color: #323232;
  height: 50px;
}
div.relative {
  position: relative;
  top: 26%;
  left: 7.6%;
  border: 0px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menubox" id="menubox1">
  <div class="relative">» test 1</div>
</div>
<p id="p1">This is a paragraph with little content.</p1>

<div class="menubox" id="menubox2">
  <div class="relative">» test 2</div>
</div>
<p id="p2">This is another small paragraph.</p2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/sq6znmm0/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("div.menubox").click(function(){
        $(this).next('p').toggle();
    });
});
```

Be aware that `p1` and `p2` are not valid HTML tags. I also removed the numbers from your `menubox`, so the jQuery matches both.

Comment: This works well when the p is a sibling of the clicked object

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function attachClickHandlers(clickElement, toggleElement) {

            $(clickElement).click(function(){
                $(toggleElement).toggle();
            });

    }

    attachClickHandlers("div.menubox1", "p1");
    attachClickHandlers("div.menubox2", "p1");
});
```

Though a good practice would also be to use spcific css class like mplungjan suggested

Comment: @mplungjan yup that was to much indeed:) Corrected my example